# Why does substitution work in the case of derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, substitution

I foraged this question on Google, but couldn't find any site explaining why the substitution works in the case of derivatives. On this site, there are questions regarding why it works in the case of integration. So why does the substitution work in the case of derivatives?

---

For example, In $\frac d{dx} \frac1{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}$, we substitute $x =\sin(\theta)$

Comment: Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: foraged which question(s) exactly?

Comment: Do you mean to ask "How does the chain rule for derivatives work?"

Comment: Yeah.. there's not really a well-known "u-substitution method" for differentiation... you must be talking about the chain rule.

Comment: It could be about parametric equations as well